# Angular 2 Update [disabled]

Tags: angular

I am trying to dynamically enable/disable a set of select inputs, based on the value of another select (true/false). However, it seems to only work on initial page load.

The form loads with the select inputs disabled. When I change the controlling input to `true`, the other inputs are now enabled.

However, they do not change back after that initial enable.

My code is as follows:

```
<tr *ngFor="let prod of seg.products">
    <td>{{prod.name}}</td>
    <td>
        <!-- The controlling selector -->
        <select [(ngModel)]="prod.isAffected" name="{{prod.name + 'AffectedSelector'}}">
            <option [value]="false" select>No</option>
            <option [value]="true">Yes</option>
        </select>
    </td>

    <!-- These load as disabled and can be changed only once -->
    <td *ngFor="let plat of platformList;let j=index">
        <select  name="{{prod.name + 'NASelector' + j}}" [disabled]="prod.isAffected">
            <option value="false" selected>No</option>
            <option value="true">Yes</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

In the component, I have tried initializing the `isAffected` value as both `false` and `null` with the exact same resultes.

I have also tried using `prod.isAffected ? true : null (and false)`.

I have also tried to just use `[ngClass]={'disabled' : prod.isAffected}`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: If you change out a select for a button or input does it work?  Just trying to rule out the select as an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused because you are using `[value]="true"` on your option. This by default is binding a string to your `[(ngModel)]` that could not be interpreted as boolean on `[disabled]`. You should use instead `[ngValue]` and the problem is fixed.

```
    <div *ngFor="let prod of products">
    <div>
      <select [(ngModel)]="prod.isAffected" name="{{prod.name + 'AffectedSelector'}}">
            <option [ngValue]="false">No</option>
            <option [ngValue]="true">Yes</option>
      </select>
      <select  name="{{prod.name + 'NASelector'}}" [disabled]="!prod.isAffected">
            <option value="false">No</option>
            <option value="true">Yes</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I made a working plunkr for you https://plnkr.co/edit/fCms5SMxTGLjE9KzXwBC?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

I've been doing some reading on this and it seems that from RC6 they removed the ability to bind to this in a two way manner.  Now you have to monitor the control for change events and call `.enable()` or `.disable()` depending on your conditions.

Another SO question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39504565/616304) and the actual Angular issue being tracked on Github [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11271#issuecomment-244507976)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. When you say use `.enable()`/`.disable()`, do you mean retrieving the select elements from the DOM and calling those methods on them from the component?

Comment: Yes, subscribe to the `onChange` event and you can get the element from the `$event` parameter in the eventHandler.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a form, which it seems you are....

You are just missing detail, namely `ngModel` in your second select. This binds the field to the form, makes it as a form control in your form.

```html
<select name="{{prod.name + 'NASelector' + j}}" ngModel 
         [disabled]="prod.isAffected">
   <option value="false" selected>No</option>
   <option value="true">Yes</option>
</select>
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/iZyicZLUC1IYHcAsA9zx?p=preview