# Angular 2 /4 Assign model value from loop index

Tags: javascript, angular, loops

I want to assign model value from the current loop index, but its not working . any idea about this

https://plnkr.co/edit/YccCBF98vCetWXJa1UJX?p=preview

```html
  <p *ngFor="let person of peoples; let i = index;">
  
  <input type="hidden" [(ngModel)]="person.displayOrder" [value]="i+1" />
  
  </p>
```

Comment: What is your intention? You want to assign i+1 to person.displayOrder?

Comment: yes exactly. its a part of darg and drop ui

Answer (score 3):

For this we need to create a custom pipe :

**HTML :**

```
<div>
    <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    <p *ngFor="let person of (peoples | changeOrder); let i= index;">
        {{person.name}} <input type="text" name='{{i}}' [(ngModel)]="person.order" />
    </p>
</div>
```

**Custom Pipe :**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'changeOrder' })
export class changeOrder implements PipeTransform {
  transform(allPeoples) {
    return allPeoples.map( ( val ,index) => { val.order = index; return val; });
  }
}
```

**NgModule :**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule,FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ App , changeOrder ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
```

Hers is the link to [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/YccCBF98vCetWXJa1UJX?p=preview) , please have a look.

Comment: Will you please set the plunker for this ?

Comment: the value setting , but not working the 2 way binding (Not changing the actual model value) , please checjk the updated plunker

Comment: @Sarath, Glad to hear that :) , will you please also accept the answer ?

Comment: @VivekDoshi why need pipe. can't we do it without pipe?

Answer (score 0):

<del>Try to use `ngValue` instead of `value`.</del> Take a look at the answer I gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45241538).

### Edit

Sorry, `ngValue` is for option on select and you have an input.
I tried your initial code and is working fine. What is your error?

Comment: Getting this error message: Can't bind to 'ngValue' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.