# Angular form control disabled binding not working

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have a form control that I disable when the page loads. When  the user clicks a button the forms should become enabled for editing. However when I toggle the property that disabled the control nothing happens.

**Template**

```
<form [formGroup]='accountForm'>
  <md-input-container>
    <input mdInput formControlName='name' />
  </md-input-container>
  <button (click)='isEditing = !isEditing'>Edit</button>
</form>
```

**Component**

```
export class AccountComponent {
  private accountForm: FormGroup;
  private isEditing = false;
  private name: FormControl = new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: !isEditing; 

  constructor(
    formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) {
    this.accountForm = formBuilder.group({
      'name': this.name
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Interesting github [thread](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11271#issuecomment-289806196) here

Comment: this.isEditing... ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2: Disable input change not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39504565/angular-2-disable-input-change-not-working)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `enable`/`disable` methods to change disable state

**template.html**

```html
<button (click)="toggleDisable()">Edit</button>
```

**component.ts**

```typescript
toggleDisable() {
  this.accountForm.get('name')[!this.isEditing ? 'enable' : 'disable']();
  this.isEditing = !this.isEditing;
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/s4Sr0uZIvIB8Ulqvfswq?p=preview)**

Answer (score 12):

According to the docs here: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl

> You can also initialize the control with a form state object on
>   instantiation, which includes both the value and whether or not the
>   control is disabled.

So setting this:

```
private name: FormControl = new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: !isEditing;
```

Is only setting how the control is initialized. It is *not* binding it nor changing it as the value of isEditing changes.

See this issue for more information: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11271

(Which I just realized is the same link that Pankaj Parkar provided in their comments.)

Comment: Thanks. I tried binding to disabled in the template initially but it results in a console warning, the inputs aren't disabled as expected and updating the value does not change the disabled state. 

Warning message: "It looks like you're using the disabled attribute with a reactive form directive. If you set disabled to true when you set up this control in your component class, the disabled attribute will actually be set in the DOM for you. We recommend using this approach to avoid 'changed after checked' errors."

Comment: This is not the way it works. Using reactiv form, you can not set the disable property from template

Comment: On my side, `disabled` in `FormControl` constructure is not working

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your template.

You have a typo on formControlName. You have `formControlName="Name"` instead of `formControlName="name"`. Notice the caps.

Moreover, isEditing is not bound to your form control object.

If you want to change the state according to `isEditing` value, then you should do something like following:

```
<form [formGroup]='accountForm'>
  <md-input-container>
    <input mdInput formControlName='name' />
  </md-input-container>
  <button (click)='toggleEditMode()'>Edit</button>
</form>
```

Note the call to a method instead.

```
export class AccountComponent {
  private accountForm: FormGroup;
  private isEditing = false;
  private name: FormControl = new FormControl({ value: '', disabled:true; 

  constructor(formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.accountForm = formBuilder.group({
      'name': this.name
    });
   }

   toggleEditMode() {
      this.isEditing = !this.isEditing;
      if(this.isEditing){
         this.name.enable();
      }else{
         this.name.disable();
   }
}
```

Comment: Oh you're correct but that was just a mistake typing the code above. My actual code doesn't have that typo. I just typed an example of what I'm trying to do.